# Problem Destroying Button Tkinter, NameError

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I am relatively new to programming with Python, and was building a fairly simple Rock Paper Scissors game with Tkinter. Basically, I have a button, that calls this function, and in this function, I want to destroy the button that I had created, but a `NameError`arises.

Here is the relative code:

```
def choose(choice):
    if choice == "rock":
        Paper.destroy()
        Scissors.destroy()

def play():
    global Rock
    Rock = Button(root, image = rock_photo, padx = 30, pady = 10, bg = "#fcf003", command = lambda: choose("rock"))
    global Paper
    Paper = Button(root,image = paper_photo, padx = 30, pady = 10, bg = "#c603fc", command=lambda: choose("paper"))
    global Scissors
    Scissors = Button(root,image = scissor_photo, padx = 30, pady = 10, bg = "#39fc03", command=lambda: choose("scissors"))

    Rock.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    Paper.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
    Scissors.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
play()
```

Furthermore, the Error:

```
NameError: name 'Paper' is not defined
```

Please let me know if I need to provide any more information. Also, I am using a 3.8 Interpreter and would like to not use classes just yet(I'm aware I'll have to start learning it soon).

Comment: `command = lambda :choose("rock")` similarly for others

Comment: Please excuse the image parameter of the Buttons, know that they are not the cause of the problem.

Comment: I didn't talk about image. I am talking about the command parameter.

Comment: It works fine after you changed all the command options to use lambda.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry i wasnt saying that in response to your comment. However, your comment is the correct answer. I will close topic shortly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`global` variables in a python function simply allow a function to read and modify a variable in the global scope. It does not create a variable. Assuming that your `play()` function is the first time that you define `Rock`, `Paper`, and `Scissors`, you must first create 3 variables outside of any function like this:

```
Rock = None
Paper = None
Scissors = None
```

Then in your `choose()` function, add the global variables, like this:

```
def choose(choice):
    global Rock
    global Paper
    global Scissors
    if choice == "rock":
        Paper.destroy()
        Scissors.destroy()
```

See [Global and Local Variables in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the `global` keyword in every scope you want to use that global variable in. This works:

```
def choose(choice):
    global Paper
    global Scissors
    if choice == "rock":
        Paper.destroy()
        Scissors.destroy()
```

But generally, for things like these, I would pass the objects as parameters to the function instead, that is:

```
def choose(choice, paper, scissors):
    if choice == "rock":
        paper.destroy()
        scissors.destroy()
```